# DOMXPath not working

Tags: php, domxpath

I am trying to get the price of products in a webshop but DOMXPath doest seem to be working.

The server is running php 5.5 and LibXML is enabled. No errors are returned, only a length of zero.

```
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();

$xmlsource = 'https://tennistoko.nl/product/professional-supreme-comfort-grip-3-st';

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($xmlsource);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);




$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');  //this catches all elements with itemprop attribute
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
   // do your stuff here with $node
   print_r($node);
}    


print_r($nodes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) is for loading HTML from a string, to load from file or url use [loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php).

```
$xmlsource = 'https://tennistoko.nl/product/professional-supreme-comfort-grip-3-st';

$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTMLFile($xmlsource);      // @ if for suppressing warnings
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');  //this catches all elements with itemprop attribute
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
   // do your stuff here with $node
   print_r($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding / at the end of the url otherwise the document is empty and use loadHTMLFile as Danijel suggested:

```
$xmlsource = 'https://tennistoko.nl/product/professional-supreme-comfort-grip-3-st/';//changed your code here
$d = new DOMDocument();
@$d->loadHTMLFile($xmlsource);      // @ if for suppressing warnings
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@itemprop]');  //this catches all elements with   itemprop attribute
foreach ($nodes as $node) { 
  // do your stuff here with $node
  print_r($node);
}
```